# In Spring 3, How to use prototype scope in controller?

Tags: spring

In Spring 3, How to use prototype scope in controller? because controllers are singleton hence i could not get the use of prototype scope. Could you please suggest a way to do this

Comment: Can you explain please why do you need this thing? Controller usually not the component that need to be singleton.

Comment: your question needs to be clearer. do you want the controller itself to have prototype scope, or do you want the singleton controller to contain objects which are created with prototype scope? An example of what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: Did any answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

add `@Scope("prototype")` on your controller

```
@Scope("prototype")
public class controller{
}
```

you can read this for proxing your beans in controller

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

> The salient point here is that the userManager bean is a singleton: it
>   will be instantiated exactly once per container, and its dependencies
>   (in this case only one, the userPreferences bean) are also injected
>   only once. This means that the userManager bean will only operate on
>   the exact same userPreferences object, that is, the one that it was
>   originally injected with.

Comment: Thanks but i still need my controllers to be singleton instance and i need to inject the prototype instances inside the controller

Comment: @user3020865 So you want to inject multiple controller instances into the same controller singleton?

Comment: yes,My controller should be singleton(@Controller) and I have Task object in controller, Task object should be prototype.

Comment: @user3020865 I added the answer, but you should describe your question better

Answer (score -1):

Specify "prototype" scope on objects which need to be prototypes:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{

    @Inject
    public void setTask(Task task) { ... }

}

@Scope("prototype")
public class Task {

}
```

Comment: i guess that controller will not have prototype scope as it singleton is the  default behaviour, in above condition we are making dependency as prototype not the controller.

Comment: @RahulSingh I think this is what the OP wants, based on his comments: "yes,My controller should be singleton(@Controller) and I have Task object in controller, Task object should be prototype."

Comment: Won't it be contradictory because when ever a singleton bean is initialized then it's dependencies will also be injected at the creation time it won't recreate it's dependencies again and again. Isn't it.

Comment: @RahulSingh well, yes, looking at this single controller it doesn't make any difference. But it makes difference, when the `Task` is injected again into other beans in the system or multiple times into the same bean

Comment: ohhkk ..that means If Task is injected into Controller then it won't make any sense if Task bean is singleton or protype because it depends parent bean's scope type, right?